# Eclipse RCP and Tycho

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, tycho

I am new to eclipse platform and RCP.

I was assigned with a task to migrate an eclipse RCP project to Tycho and adding backend communication to pull live data.

my questions are:

1. where can I find up to date documentation on RCP?
2. where can I find up to date documentation on Tycho?
3. sample application for both Tycho and RCP working together with unit tests and application?
4. Can I install RCP on top of standard eclipse IDE or do I have to use the specific IDE for RCP?

Many thanks in advance.

Gadi.

Comment: The Eclipse RCP can be added to any Eclipse installation through the Add Software.

Comment: Eclipse RCP means more or less _built on Eclipse_ or _Eclipse-based_. To develop Eclipse RCP applications use the [Plug-in Development Environment (PDE)](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/) which is included by default (otherwise you have to install it) in the _Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers_ and _Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers_. Answers to your first three questions will be found in the help/documentation of [Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/index.jsp) and of [Tycho](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/documentation.php) (including a demo project).

Comment: An Eclipse RCP is a standalone program composed of plug-ins and the core Eclipse code. Sorry, but this question is far too broad for SO, try reading the references in the other comments and come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/eclipse/chemclipse uses the latest version of Eclipse Tycho. It also features unit tests https://github.com/eclipse/chemclipse/tree/develop/chemclipse/tests I suggest https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html as an alternative to the sparse official documentation. I use https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2023-03/r/eclipse-ide-rcp-and-rap-developers personally which ships everything you need, but you can also install the necessary plugins afterward from a slimmer edition.